# qt, extern construction and indefined reference

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to compile library with Qt Creator from sources with 'extern' construction:

```
A.cpp
int A = 5;

B.cpp
extern int A;

void foo()
{ A=10; }
```

But got an error: undefined reference to 'A' from 'foo()'. Both files are added to project.

Comment: Are you sure you added both A.cpp and B.cpp to your .pro file?

Comment: Are you sure these variables aren't inside some namespace?

Comment: @Apprentice Queue absolutely